# stack: NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id

Tags: javascript, selenium, jenkins, mocha.js

The problem is I write autotests. Stack: js + chai +mocha+selenium. When running tests using mocha, the first test passes and completes, and the following tests simply do not run. Here is the error itself: NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id and may no longer be used. The first test:

```
describe('Tests Accrual History', async function () {

beforeEach(async function () {
baseurl = 'Url'
await AccrualHistory.goToUrl(baseurl);

});



it('Tests Accrual History', async function () {
await AccrualHistory.login();
await AccrualHistory.AccrualHistoryTest();
})


afterEach(async function () {
await AccrualHistory.CloseBroweser();
});
})
```

The second test:

```
describe('Tests Add Pass', async function () {

beforeEach(async function () {
baseurl = 'URL'
await AddPass.goToUrl(baseurl);

});



it('Tests Add Pass', async function () {
await AddPass.login();
await AddPass.AddPassTest();


})


afterEach(async function () {
await AddPass.CloseBroweser();
});
})
```

What is in the basepage

```
const {By,until, Key, Builder, Browser} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { assert } = require('chai');
var should = require("chai").should();
const driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
driver.manage().window().maximize();




class BasePage{

    constructor() {
        global.driver = driver;
    }
    
    
    async goToUrl(baseurl){
        await driver.get(baseurl);
    }

    
    async WaitEl(ElWait){
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(ElWait),20000);
    }
    
    
    async FindElClick(El){
        await driver.findElement(El).click();

    }

    
    async login(){
        
        await this.FindElClick(By.linkText(''));
        await this.AssertPassNotUrl((By.xpath('//*[@id="window-auth"]/form/div[1]')), '');
        await this.FindElClick(By.linkText(''));
        await this.WaitEl(By.id('choice_adaptive'));
        await this.AssertPassUrl(By.xpath('//*[@id="choice_adaptive"]/div[3]'), '', 'personal/info/'); 
    }

    
    async AssertPassNotUrl(FindElPass, ElPass){
        let test = await driver.findElement(FindElPass).getText().then(function(test){
            return test
        });
        test.should.equal(ElPass);
    }

    // проверка с URL
    async AssertPassUrl(FindElPass, ElPass, Url){
        const main_url = '';
        let test = await driver.findElement(FindElPass).getText().then(function(test){
            return test
        });
        test.should.equal(ElPass);
        let url = await driver.getCurrentUrl();
        url.should.equal(main_url + Url);
    }

    
    async AssertOnlyUrl(Url){
        const main_url = '';
        let url = await driver.getCurrentUrl();
        url.should.equal(main_url + Url);
    }

    

    
    async BackLink(){
        await this.FindElClick(By.linkText("Назад"));
    }

    
    async EnterText(ElEnter, Text){
        await driver.findElement(ElEnter).sendKeys(Text, Key.ENTER);
    }

    
    async EnterTextNoEnter(ElEnter, Text){
        await driver.findElement(ElEnter).sendKeys(Text);
    }

    
    async GetValue(ElValue, TextValue){
        let ToDoText = await driver.findElement(ElValue).getAttribute('value').then(function(ToDoText){
            return ToDoText
          });
          ToDoText.should.equal(TextValue);
    }

    
    async ClearText(FindElClear){
        await driver.findElement(FindElClear).clear();
    }

    
    async TrueCheckBox(ElCheckBox){
        let box = await driver.findElement(ElCheckBox).isSelected().then(function(box){
            return box
          });
          box.should.equal(true);
    }

    
    async OkAlert(){
        await driver.wait(until.alertIsPresent());
        let alert = await driver.switchTo().alert();
        await alert.accept();
    }


    async CloseBroweser(){
        await driver.close();  
    }

}

module.exports = BasePage;
```

I guess that the error is in opening or exiting, since after closing the first test everything crashes. Also, if I run 5 tests in parallel, only 3 of them are run. As I understood after closing the first test, the second one does not start so it was closed, but I do not know how to fix it

Comment: HI! Could you provide the stacktrace. Most of the time helpful information is included.

Comment: @JordiLaforge hi. I add new info